# ZXing library and ZXing.org differences?

Tags: zxing

I have implemented ZXing-node and am able to scan generated QRcode images great, however any images captured via a phone camera, don't get recognized, even though I've added some GraphicsWizard manipulation to deblur, resize etc.
I have tried using the --try_harder option as well, without success.

However the ZXing.org website handles all of these without any issues, where can I find out what settings, or additional image manipulation are done here?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also all open source: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/zxingorg
It uses TRY_HARDER mode, and different binarizers, and will try PURE_BARCODE mode too.

Comment: I've tried the TRY_HARDER option without success, will give PURE_BARCODE a go next

Comment: Unless the barcode is a 'pure' synthetic image straight out of a generator, it won't matter. I think the difference is probably trying other binarizers.